# Reset Nginx static content caching

Tags: nginx

I have the following inside the server block of the nginx configuration:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires 365d;
}
```

This seems great for files that almost never change but when they do change, what do you do to indicate to the clients loading these static files that something has changed? My initial thoughts are to change 'expires 365d' to 'expires 1d' but there must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Cache-Control` header set by the `expires` directive will tell the Browser how and when the file will be request from the server again.

It's the recommended way of dooing so. All good! No direct need to change it to "just" 1d. I control the caching behaviour of the browser with the URL to the resource. Let me make an example:

A css or image file on the server. `main.css` and `logo.jpg`. In the HTML do something like
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css?version=1" .......>`. After changing the css file increase the version-number or simply change it to something else.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css?version="2" .......>`

Your Browser: "Hey that file got changed - I'll go get it!".

I have two different methods of "version numbering":

- 1,2,3.....
- git commit hash of a file.

What ever is good for you.

Comment: This is a nice solution to doing it but it can become a problem if you have many images or many css files that is referenced from many places (many html files or php scripts for example)

Comment: Mhhh In case I'll find another good solution I will let you know but as the `Cache-Control` header works in the clients browser its hard to do this dynamically. The Browser is not even sending a request to the server for the cached files. Maybe an ETAG could be the better solution here.